# scroll not showing on either side

Tags: html, css

hello friends please help me with this issue
scroll not showing on either side of the page.
i am using body with 100% height and width
but the inner elements have specific width and height, which supposed to show scroll when window zooms... 
please tell me why it is behaving so and how can i resolve this..

css is like this..

```
body {
margin:0 0 0 0;
height:100%;
width:100%;
}
.hdr{
    width: 1500px;
    height:1500px;
}
```

html

```
<body>
     <div class="hdr"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: -1 Why the PHP/JQuery/Js tag? What have you tried?

Comment: it has no to do with body it makes the same problem while using a tag how is absolutly.

Answer (score 1):

In CSS, add `overflow: scroll` in body if you want full page scroll or in `.hdr` if you want internal scroll....

Answer (score 0):

You should use `min-height`

```
body {
    margin:0 0 0 0;
    min-height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: are you referring to vertical scroll or horizontal scroll?